# CLLocationManager - Custom location manager in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios, location, cllocationmanager

I am very new to this technology so please help me.

I am using CLLocationManager to get current location and my application has custom settings showing status that he has allowed for current location or not i.e. message prompt which comes by default when we write

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

If user taps on don't allow on that message prompt and goes back to my application custom setting and changes off button for getting location to on, can I get current location of user.

How this thing can be implemented?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once location services have been user denied for your app it can only be turned back on in the general settings - so tell the user that then send them there. (You might want to use a UIAlertView to notify them first.)

```
// If Location Services are disabled, restricted or denied.
if ((![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    || ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    || ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied))
{
    // Send the user to the location settings preferences
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using the `prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES` URL no longer works as of iOS 5.1: [http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2011/11/04/settings-urls/]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is "YES." When the user enables location service for your app through settings, it will be just as if the user answered yes when they were prompted. You can check for whether location service is enabled for your app by checking authorization status in code, thusly:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) 
{
    //Get user's current location


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my issue is that when user says no initially for getting location and then want to get current location, so can he change in my application custom setting?

Comment: Why do a custom settings for location services when you are getting this for free on the device settings? In any case, the system would need to be notified that the user changed his or her mind. How do you think the system can guarantee that the user did indeed change their mind if only your app knows about it? It should be obvious that the system need to provide the interface in order to guarantee the user's answer is correct; the system notifies each app. So direct your users to the settings menu to change their choice for your app if they chose to not authorize your app the first time.